# Reserve physical memory from kernel but keep logical mapping

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, driver, embedded-linux

I'm working on a 32-bit embedded system with 1GB RAM that has an unusual configuration.  There exists a 32MB region of RAM(DDR) that is used by an external piece of hardware.  This region has size and alignment requirements defined by the hardware and the physical address and size are fixed during boot time before Linux kernels execute.  The system also has two independent CPUs (not 2 cores on the same CPU) each running Linux that share the same 1GB of RAM and also need to simultaneously access the 32MB region of RAM.

I need to give each CPU an arbitrary amount of RAM to run Linux and I also need to allow each CPU to access the 32MB region.  I have got all of this working by specifying the memory map on the kernel command line (e.g. for CPU1 memmap=512M@0 and for CPU2 memmap=512M@512M) and also using memmap=32M$XXXX to reserve the 32MB region.  When the kernels boot, I use ioremap map the 32MB region into each kernels virtual address space so it can access the region.

However, what I've found is that to maintain software compatibility with existing kernel drivers, I need the 32MB region to be mapped into both kernels' "logical" address space so that phys_to_virt and virt_to_phys will work.  Of course, when using ioremap, the 32MB region maps into the vmalloc area, so phys_to_virt and virt_to_phys don't work as desired.

I'm not finding any way to accomplish what I need to do with existing command-line or build-configuration options.

From a high-level, I think the kernels' page table entries will have no translation where the gap in the physical/logical memory map was specified (i.e.  memmap=32M$XXXX) and what I need to do is to make sure those page table entries have the same information as if the gap was never specified.  Or find a way to "reserve" a specific region of physical RAM from the kernel after it has mapped the logical address space into the page table.  Either way, any manipulation needs to be done before the kernel starts using the memory.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have a similar need and have not found a solution.

Comment: Nothing, yet.  We moved some of the functionality from one CPU to the other so that one of the CPUs doesn't need to perform phys_to_virt, but also lost some performance.